# name is not defined for twitch-viewer module

Tags: python, cmd, module, pip, twitch

I can not start the https://github.com/ohyou/twitch-viewer because of a NameError. I did the following on CMD:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.720]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

C:\Users\Nesin>pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\nesin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\nesin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests) (1.25.8)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\nesin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\nesin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2.9)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\nesin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)

C:\Users\Nesin>pip install json
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement json (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for json

C:\Users\Nesin>pip install simplejson
Requirement already satisfied: simplejson in c:\users\nesin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (3.17.0)

C:\Users\Nesin>pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\nesin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\nesin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests) (1.25.8)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\nesin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2.9)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\nesin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\nesin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2019.11.28)

C:\Users\Nesin>pip install livestreamer
Requirement already satisfied: livestreamer in c:\users\nesin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (1.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0,>=1.0 in c:\users\nesin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from livestreamer) (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\nesin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=1.0->livestreamer) (2.9)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\nesin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=1.0->livestreamer) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\nesin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=1.0->livestreamer) (1.25.8)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\nesin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0,>=1.0->livestreamer) (2019.11.28)
```

Then I did this here on Python:

```
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

import simplejson
import json
import requests
import livestreamer
nesgaming
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
NameError: name 'nesgaming' is not defined
```

Can someone help me with this one? :)

Comment: [There is no `nesgaming`](https://github.com/ohyou/twitch-viewer/search?q=nesgaming&unscoped_q=nesgaming) in the repository. What do want to do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you intend to call come function from twitch-viewer.py with the argument "nesgaming".

You're telling Python "nesgaming," as if it were some variable, but you're not telling Python what "nesgaming" is or what to do with it.

I am unsure how your code block with the pip install statements relates to the question. You're not dealing with an import error as far as I can tell.

Comment: Here is the description to the module: https://github.com/ohyou/twitch-viewer

.. what must i do after importing? :-)